# Clustering google map markers

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-markers

I would like to know what is the best way to `cluster map markers`? We are currently using google maps in our application, where every entity defines a point on a map and have a `grid based clustering algorithm (64px X 64px grid)` for clustering the entity points. This worked fine for around 80k entities. We have datasets varying from 5000 to 1.5 million entities. 
The problem with `1.5 million dataset` is that with so many markers, almost every grid on the map is a clustered marker, which not only results in a bad UI (a clustered marker at every grid), but also increases the load time for the map.

1) `Client Side` - I have tried client side clustering (`Map Clusterer`). Which didn't work, as the json object itself with 1.5 million entities slowed the system, also Map Clusterer worked only upto 50k markers.

2) `Server Side` - The problem with such huge datasets is that i cannot even query all the entities, so i was thinking of having a first level of grid based clustering in SQL and then have some density based clustering after getting the first pass clustered result from SQL with every cluster having a clusterCount and avg lat/long.
Or if there is a better idea for such huge datasets, (I read about `MAFIA, CLIQUE` clustering http://www.siam.org/proceedings/datamining/2001/dm01_07NageshH.pdf ).

Also, at some point, i would really like to cache this data (although that should be asked in a separate question),  but if someone could also give some caching technique keeping in mind the clusters, view port and zoom level, that'll be really helpful.

Comment: At this point i would take anything as an answer...has anyone tried K-means or quad trees for clustering?

Answer (score 0):

You can try my kmeans server-side solution:

https://github.com/biodiv/anycluster

(it is in python/geodjango/postgis)

If you have a truckload of cash, you can take a look at:

http://www.maptimize.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into GeoHash: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash

Could also use Solr for indexing spatial data: Search API21 and
Apache Solr Search Integration22